# How to wait for function to finish before running another one or rest of the code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I can't figure this one out. I have one function that connects to an SFTP server and downloads files. Then, I have a second function that reads the contents, puts the data in an array, and returns the array.

The problem is that the second function always runs first. I tried different methods but I can't get it to work. That connection to SFTP is quite slow, it can take like 10+ seconds to finish. But I need to somehow wait for it to finish before doing anything else.

```
const SFTPConfig = require('../config/keys').sftpconfig;

const getCSATFiles = async function(targetDate) {
  try {
    let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
    let sftp = new Client();
    const date = moment(targetDate);

    var dir = `../csv/${targetDate}/`;

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }

    sftp
      .connect(SFTPConfig, 'once')
      .then(() => {
        return sftp.list('/In/Archives/');
      })
      .then(data => {
        data.forEach(item => {
          const fileName = item.name;
          const remotePath = '/In/Archives/' + fileName;

          const localePath = path.join(dir + fileName);

          if (
            moment(item.modifyTime)
              .format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm')
              .toString()
              .slice(0, 10) ===
            date
              .format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm')
              .toString()
              .slice(0, 10)
          ) {
            sftp
              .fastGet(remotePath, localePath, {})
              .then(() => {
                console.log('finished getting the files!');
                sftp.end();
              })
              .catch(err => {
                sftp.end();
                console.log(err, 'fastGet method error');
              });
          }
        });
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const readCSVFiles = async function(targetDate) {
  try {
    const casesBO = [];

    var dir = `../csv/${targetDate}/`;

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }

    const allLocalFiles = path.join(__dirname, dir);
    const readDir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

    const files = await readDir(allLocalFiles);

    for (let file of files) {
      fs.createReadStream(allLocalFiles + file)
        .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true, delimiter: ';' }))
        .on('error', error => console.error(error))
        .on('data', row => {
          if (row['[REGION2]'] !== 'FR') {
            casesBO.push(row['[CALLERNO_EMAIL_SOCIAL]']);
            console.log(
              `${row['[AGENT]']} is ${row['[REGION2]']} and case = ${
                row['[CALLERNO_EMAIL_SOCIAL]']
              }`
            );
          }
        })
        .on('end', rowCount => {
          console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`);
        });
    }
    return casesBO;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const testFunc = async () => {
  const csatfiles = await getCSATFiles('2021-02-03');

  const boData = await readCSVFiles('2021-02-03');
  console.log(boData);
};
testFunc();
```

Comment: you are missing the `return` statement in `getCSATFiles`. You need to write a `return` before `sftp.connect` => `return sftp.connect(....)`

Comment: Don't mix `async-await` syntax with `promise-chaning`. Consider using either one of them, not both at the same time in your code. For example: instead of chaining `then()` method to `sftp.connect(...)`, just await it: `await sftp.connect(...)`. Once you have the data, return it from your first function.

Comment: @Yousaf yes, you are right. But anyway the promise will be fullfilled directly and not at the time when the OP wants it to resolve. But yes, my 2nd comment is wrong.

Comment: consider getCSATFiles('2021-02-03').then(() => readCSVFiles('2021-02-03'));

Comment: Hey guys, I tried the above solutions but none of them make the first function finish first. The second one still runs before the first one has time to download the files. 

below is what I see in the console. the files are read before they finish downloading.

Parsed 8 rows
Parsed 10 rows
Parsed 12 rows
finished getting the files!

Comment: @Yousaf the sftp module uses callbacks, not sure how I would make it work without. It first establishes a connection with SFTP.connect and then you have a callback to do things.

Answer (score 0):

#1 as @messerbill suggested, you need to return the promise from your function.
#2 your promise has a loop inside of it that have more promises. In this case, you need to collect those promises and use Promise.all to resolve them before you second function runs. I put comments on the lines you need to change below. Try this:

```
const SFTPConfig = require('../config/keys').sftpconfig;

const getCSATFiles = function(targetDate) {
  try {
    let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
    let sftp = new Client();
    const date = moment(targetDate);

    var dir = `../csv/${targetDate}/`;

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }
    // I return the promise here
    return sftp
      .connect(SFTPConfig, 'once')
      .then(() => {
        return sftp.list('/In/Archives/');
      })
      .then(data => {
        // I set up my promises as a blank array
        const promises = [];
        data.forEach(item => {
          const fileName = item.name;
          const remotePath = '/In/Archives/' + fileName;

          const localePath = path.join(dir + fileName);

          if (
            moment(item.modifyTime)
              .format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm')
              .toString()
              .slice(0, 10) ===
            date
              .format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm')
              .toString()
              .slice(0, 10)
          ) {
            // I collect the promises here
            promises.push(sftp
              .fastGet(remotePath, localePath, {})
              .then(() => {
                console.log('finished getting the files!');
                sftp.end();
              })
              .catch(err => {
                sftp.end();
                console.log(err, 'fastGet method error');
              }));
          }
        });
        // I resolve them here
        return Promise.all(promises);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const readCSVFiles = async function(targetDate) {
  try {
    const casesBO = [];

    var dir = `../csv/${targetDate}/`;

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }

    const allLocalFiles = path.join(__dirname, dir);
    const readDir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

    const files = await readDir(allLocalFiles);

    for (let file of files) {
      fs.createReadStream(allLocalFiles + file)
        .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true, delimiter: ';' }))
        .on('error', error => console.error(error))
        .on('data', row => {
          if (row['[REGION2]'] !== 'FR') {
            casesBO.push(row['[CALLERNO_EMAIL_SOCIAL]']);
            console.log(
              `${row['[AGENT]']} is ${row['[REGION2]']} and case = ${
                row['[CALLERNO_EMAIL_SOCIAL]']
              }`
            );
          }
        })
        .on('end', rowCount => {
          console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`);
        });
    }
    return casesBO;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const testFunc = async () => {
  const csatfiles = await getCSATFiles('2021-02-03');

  const boData = await readCSVFiles('2021-02-03');
  console.log(boData);
};
testFunc();
```

Comment: It does not work. When doing it this way, the second function doesn't seem to run at all. I don't see the console.logs from it. When i use this code in my api endpoint, it stalls and nothing happens anymore. I'm starting to think it's an issue or limitation of the sftp module.

Comment: no error no. It just exited after it ran. I saw the message that the files were downloaded and then that's it. It finished normally. I don't think there is any error, it just ends the program after it resolves and nothing else runs.

Comment: Also, if I use forEach() function from a module called p-iteration, then the rest of the code will execute but the second function will still finish first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care, that you return the promise you want to resolve inside the function body in order to get the promise resolved at the right time.

```js
async function promiseNotReturned() {
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve.bind(null), 5000))
}

async function promiseReturned() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve.bind(null), 5000))
}

async function run() {
  await promiseNotReturned()
  console.log("does not wait for 5 seconds")
  await promiseReturned()
  console.log("waits for 5 seconds")
}

run()
```

Comment: I tried this too and the second function will no longer run. It seems that after the promise is resolved or you return a promise, it returns for the whole file, and everything after won't run. Even if the return statement is inside the function, it just seems to end everything.